# why doesnt this CREATE TABLE query work

Tags: php, mysqli

```
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE tickets
    (
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(32),
    Email VARCHAR(40),
    Subject VARCHAR(40),
    Subject TEXT(500),
    open VARCHAR(10)
    )";

$con->query($sql);
```

Why doesnt the MySQLi query above work? I have succesfully established connection with the database

Comment: Are you checking the return value? Seeing if the database is reporting an error? Does that SQL work when you run it directly in the database?

Comment: Is your problem resolved ?

Answer (score 2):

You have a duplicate column which is Subject.

```
Schema Creation Failed: Duplicate column name 'Subject'
```

Rename one of your two columns, for example :

```
 $sql = "CREATE TABLE tickets
        (
        ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        Name VARCHAR(32),
        Email VARCHAR(40),
        Subject VARCHAR(40),
        Subject_text TEXT(500),
        open VARCHAR(10)
        )";

 $con->query($sql);
```

You can use this website http://sqlfiddle.com/ for SQL tests :)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 Subject fields. Rename one of them:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE tickets
(
ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR(32),
Email VARCHAR(40),
Subject VARCHAR(40),  // HERE
Subject TEXT(500),   // HERE
open VARCHAR(10)
)";
```